# What is this hanging, green-white plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health

I brought this plant and it didn't have a name or instructions attached to it as other ones they sell. Would anyone know what kind of plant this is and how to maintain it? It's really pretty and I would hate for it to die due to ignorance.

[image: plant view one]

[image: plant view two]

[image: plant view three]

[image: plant view four]

Comment: To OP, could you please attach a few more images, especially showing the stem and branches? Thanks.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor  Sure.

Comment: Thanks much. Those are Pothos stems alright. This is the Marble Queen Variegated Pothos. One last thing if I may, does the Home Depot barcode display an SKU code? I would like to be absolutely sure!

Comment: Yup, it's a pothos as Srihari says, just a new variety

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Nope, no code anywhere on the pot. Normally I would see a code and the name of the plant but this one doesn't

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Thanks for inquiring thus far. But I'm still lost as to how I should maintain it. Should I just research the web? ....I may get all types of information on how to maintain it; so what would be your input, if you dont mind.

Comment: The plant is very easy to maintain. 1. Keep indoors in low to moderate light. Filtered sunlight will do. 2. Keep in room temperature. 3. Like all Pothos, water and keep moist. 4. Feed sparingly, maybe once a year or so. 5. Cut back about once a year or if it grows fast, sooner. You can use the cuttings to transplant into new pots if you wish.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Perfect. Just what I needed to know. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is "Marble Queen" Pothos, a variegated variety of Pothos, Epipremnum aureum. This is a very easy to maintain houseplant. It is also quite easy to propagate.

Please refer to the internet where extensive information on maintenance is available. Low to moderate light, moist soil and very occasional fertilization is all that is usually needed. I'd definitely keep the plant away from pets.

FYI, I grow this outdoors in Zone 9B in a very shaded area.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is Epipremnum (Pothos), I'm wondering if it might be Peperomia obtusifolia variegata.The leaves on Peperomia are thicker or more fleshy with a more generally rounded shape, whereas Epripremnum has more consistently pointed, heart shaped leaves. Image and info:

http://www.south-florida-plant-guide.com/peperomia.html

UPDATE

Now you've added more pics, the way that longer stem curls back on itself means it has to be Epipremnum - but I'm pretty sure its not Marble Queen. Could be 'Pearls and Jade', a newer sport from Marble Queen, or even Epipremnum N'Joy, though the two are remarkably similar in appearance - image of E. N'joy in link below. Both these varieties are said to be more compact than others. Either way it's an Epipremnum, common name Pothos. Relatively easy to care for, does not appear to need higher light levels than the plain green version, retaining its coloration well in shade. They're not too keen on direct sunlight, so a position in bright to medium light should be fine. Water liberally spring through to end of summer, but allow the potting medium to dry out slightly between waterings - just so it's a little dry to the touch, but not so dry it's shrunk from the sides of the pot.

http://www.canarius.com/en/plants/epipremnum-aureum-cv-n-joy.html

Also looks like it'll need repotting next spring, there's a lot of plant compared to size of pot. If you lived next door, I'd be nipping a cutting or two of that, it's a little beauty - never seen it here in the UK - yet.

Comment: Peperomia is a shrub. This is definitely Pothos. I have grown multiple plants training them to hang and climb. The running branches are more telling than the leaves themselves.

Comment: might be a shrub where you are, in the UK, its a houseplant! I'm just not certain whether its Peperomia or Epipremnum...

Comment: It is still possible to grow it as a house plant, no doubt. From the link you posted, if this can grow in Florida, it can grow in CA and I am actually planning to see if local nurseries carry it. I am just commenting on the branch style, and looking at the photo posted by OP, my conclusion is that it is Pothos and not Peperomia.

Comment: You may be right - I repeat, I'm not sure...its a nice plant though, whichever it is.

Comment: Sigh, I think Bamboo is correct on this one!  Pothos variegation is more striped rather than splotches.  Peperonmia variegated looks exactly like this OP's plant.  I thought Pothos as well until I looked at Bamboo's suggestion.  And amazingly, I just learned BOTH are toxic for cats and dogs.  Every day, if I don't learn something new I am disappointed.  Thanks guys!!  Brit gal!!

Comment: @stormy - learning something new every day is possible - what's difficult is remembering it all. Or maybe that's just me, hmmm...

Comment: I don't think it is Pothos, reminds me of a variegated hoya. Of course it could be a joke, a plastic plant

Comment: Luckily I haven't reached the point of not recognizing stuff I should know, YET!  Grins.  This getting old crap pisses me off so badly. Grrr.  I mean ALL THAT WORK, all that work to know stuff we could have used when younger and finally GETTING it and then...we die.  More grrrr.  I've got pretty set avenues of information to pull up when necessary. This forum helps to check on my knowledge and weed out stuff that is wrong. Always checking to see if what I know is still correct.  If not talk about 'spring cleaning'...sighs!

Comment: Pretty sure it is Peperomia...not Pothos or Hoya.  One look at Bamboo's sites is sorta kinda a duh howdy.  This is so much fun to work with such incredible, knowledgeable, plant people!  If this is not Peperomia I will be amazed and again learn something new (like a bit more humility)!

Comment: I am very convinced this is Pothos. Peperomia is new to me, but a look at the stem and a comparison with my own Marble Queen convinces me otherwise. Though the original question has been edited, I know the OP bought this at Home Depot, and they don't seem to carry this online. I might look into this closer. Also, an internet search for Peperomia obtusifolia variegata is not returning results that look similar to this plant, but I might just not have looked deep enough.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor still looks like peperomia to me, but I do take your point about the length of the branches - I would dearly love to see the plant in the flesh...